# Random colored column?

Tags: vim

For whatever reason, the first column is highlighted and I can't figure out why.  I have not messed with my vimrc file, nor any zsh options.  This column is only highlighted only with, "aliases.zsh", file.  Opening any other file, or filetype, the highlighted column is non-existent.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be either the *fold column* (showing nothing because no folds have been found). You can turn that off via

```
:set foldcolumn=0
```

You can find out where that was set via `:verbose set foldcolumn?`, and then remove / undo that.

Or it could be the *signs column*, which should disappear if you remove all signs via

```
:sign unplace *
```

Comment: The latter proved to be the solution to the issue, but how could this have started in the first place?  I have no mappings for, `sign unplace *`, whatsoever.

Comment: Probably a plugin defining some signs.

Answer (score 0):

That's a scroll bar that's been bound to the left side of your window instead of the right side. Look at the bottom of that file for a embedded `vim` command sequence (**NOTE:** they're called modelines). It's likely telling `vim` to add the scroll bar to that side of your file.

Comment: How do I remove/change it?

Comment: Take a look at this `vim` wiki tip to see if resolves your issue: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Hide_toolbar_or_menus_to_see_more_text

Comment: There nothing at the bottom of the file except, `bot`.

Comment: What does the output of `:set` show?

Comment: `:set` didn't show any options that I did not set myself.  @Ingo Karkat managed to find exactly what the issue was.  It was `:sign unlace *`.

Comment: @Brandon - ha, I never even heard of these before. WOW! If you read through the `:help signs` it explains them. Did you do something with a debugger that may have triggered them?

Comment: I already read through the help.  Honestly, I did not do anything, in regards to the debugger, that would have trigger it.  I simply opened the file, made a quick change, and closed the current shell.